# How to filter a schedule to return a list of employees based on date and shift code?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

In Google Sheets, I have an employee work shift scheduling sheet named `Shifts2`.

- Column A lists all employees.
- Row 1 is a list of dates in November.
- The remaining rows in columns B through AG contain shift codes.

On any given date, scheduled employees have a shift code entered in their row.

- Multiple employees work each shift
- Employees who share a shift also share the same code.

### Sample Data: `Shifts2`

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Names** | **01/11/2023** | **02/11/2023** |
| **2** | Landon Jameson | DO | DO |
| **3** | Avery Rose | 17-01 | 17-01 |
| **4** | Makayla Grace | 22-06 | 22-06 |
| **5** | Kamryn Elizabeth | 09-17 | 09-17 |
| **6** | Jovanny Alexander | 17-01 | 17-01 |
| **7** | Lila Marie | DO | DO |
| **8** | Kamila Nicole | 09-17 | 09-17 |
| **9** | Jovany Michael | DO | 06-14 |
| **10** | Liliana Faith | 17-01 | 17-01 |

In the sheet `Selections`, I want a formula that returns a list of employee names based on a specified date and shift code.

- `A2` contains the lookup date
- `C2` contains a shift code
- `C7` contains the formula.

How can I accomplish this?  I also intend to reuse the formula in `D7` using the same date but with a different shift (specified in `D2`).

### Sample Results: `Selections`

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Select a Date** |  | **1st Shift** | **2nd Shift** |
| **2** | 01/11/2023 |  | 09-17 | 17-01 |
| **3** |  |  |  |  |
| **4** |  |  |  |  |
| **5** |  |  |  |  |
| **6** |  |  | **Agents on 1st Shift** | **Agents on 2nd Shift** |
| **7** |  |  | Kamryn Elizabeth | Avery Rose |
| **8** |  |  | Kamila Nicole | Jovanny Alexander |
| **9** |  |  |  | Liliana Faith |

[Link to my Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lm9BO-xrlF2Ie1Sz7yjERW5ixXQr-Oi2Sp5BEbNaRWI/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Important Note: Formula Localization

@maidenas' locale uses **`,`** as the decimal separator ( **½=0,5** ) and the formula syntax is slightly different for separating arguments and array elements than locales that use **`.`** as the decimal separator ( **½=0.5** ) such as North America (NA).  NA versions of the formulas are included at the bottom of the post.

---

### Formula

FILTER is often combined with INDEX and MATCH in similar situations.  I have also sorted the results by name. SORT can be removed if unwanted.

The first 2 formulas are equivalent:

```
=SORT(FILTER(Shifts2!A1:A100; 
   INDEX(Shifts2!1:100;;
     MATCH(A2;Shifts2!1:1;0))=C2))
```

```
=LET(data;Shifts2!1:100;
   SORT(FILTER(INDEX(data;;1); 
     INDEX(data;;MATCH(
       A2;INDEX(data;1);0))=C2)))
```

To perform the calculation for both shifts (or even more) using a single formula in `C7` use the following formula.  Note it also includes a staff count above the names.

```
=LET(data;Shifts2!1:100;
   MAP(C2:D2; LAMBDA(shift;
     LET(staff; FILTER(INDEX(data;;1); 
       INDEX(data;;MATCH(A2;INDEX(data;1);0))=shift);
         {"Staff Count: "&COUNTA(staff);SORT(staff)}))))
```

[image: Multi-Column Example]

---

### Functions Used

[COUNTA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093993) [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150) [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377) [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535) [LET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093305) [MAP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094290) [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379) [SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624)

---

### North American Syntax

```
=SORT(FILTER(Shifts2!A1:A100, 
   INDEX(Shifts2!1:100,,
     MATCH(A2,Shifts2!1:1,0))=C2))
```

```
=LET(data,Shifts2!1:100,
   SORT(FILTER(INDEX(data,,1), 
     INDEX(data,,MATCH(
       A2,INDEX(data,1),0))=C2)))
```

```
=LET(data,Shifts2!1:100,
   MAP(C2:D2, LAMBDA(shift,
    LET(staff, FILTER(INDEX(data,,1), 
     INDEX(data,,MATCH(A2,INDEX(data,1),0))=shift),
       {"Staff Count: "&COUNTA(staff);SORT(staff)}))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found the solution.

I just used a filter inside a filter.
Firstly I filtered all the employees who worked the date I chose, and then I filtered the results based on the shift code.

Formula in C7:

```
=FILTER(Shifts2!A2:A52;FILTER(Shifts2!B2:AG52;Shifts2!B1:AE1=A2)=C2)
```

Formula in D7:

```
=FILTER(Shifts2!A2:A52;FILTER(Shifts2!B2:AG52;Shifts2!B1:AE1=A2)=D2)
```